# Can't find element using CSS Selector or xPath in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, automation, protractor

I'm trying to make an automation test using Protractor, but I can't click on any element I want to... I'm very new to Angular and I'm just learning Protractor. Here is the element I'm trying to click:

```
<div _ngcontent-bhx-c21="" class="mg-country" title="CAN"><div _ngcontent-bhx-c21="" class="country-image CAN"></div><span _ngcontent-bhx-c21="" class="country-text">CAN</span></div>
```

This is the error I'm getting, testing on Chrome with Mac OS:

*Failed: script timeout
(Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.82)
(Driver info: chromedriver=93.0.4577.63 (ff5c0da2ec0adeaed5550e6c7e98417dac77d98a-refs/branch-heads/4577@{#1135}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64)*

This is one thing I've tried:

```
describe('login page', function () {
    it('should select a location', function () {

        browser.get('https://app.io');

        element(by.css('[title="CAN"]')).click();

        browser.sleep(2000);
    });
});
```

I've also tried replacing the '[title="CAN"]' with the xPath, (which I've read should not be used in Angular but it didn't work anyway), and the CSS Selector path.

I have 3 other country option buttons, and the only difference between them all is the title, so I'm thinking that needs to be my identifier, but I just can't get it to work.

When the app initially loads, it attempts to go to the url specified, but it's soon redirected to a different page which is the page that contains the element I'm trying to locate. I've also tried initially loading the page it gets redirected to and that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
element(by.css('[title=CAN]')).click();
```

or

```
elements(by.css('.mg-country')).get(0).click();
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion, but unfortunately still got the script timeout... With the second, I got "Failed: elements is not defined". I then tried it again removing the "s" from elements and got, "Failed: element(...).get is not a function".